# how to get list of json data in listview using model class?

Tags: flutter

I want to get all subjects data in list view like subjectName, image etc.

I get data from simple json but cant get from list of json.

The response are as below,

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "subject": [
    {
      "subject_id": "5e32874c714fa",
      "subject_name": "Account",
      "image": "upload/subject/Account.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5da9ff659fb7c",
      "subject_name": "Biology",
      "image": "upload/subject/03_logo-1164x484.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5da9ff990b1c6",
      "subject_name": "Chemisty",
      "image": "upload/subject/02_logo-1168x490.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5de76afbd064e",
      "subject_name": "Computer",
      "image": "upload/subject/07_logo-1169x486.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5d788906c431b",
      "subject_name": "Devsatya Paperset March 2020",
      "image": "upload/subject/04_logo-1174x491.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    }
  ]
}
```

And i created Model Class from app.quicktype.io/ as below.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final subjectByUser = subjectByUserFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

SubjectByUser subjectByUserFromJson(String str) => SubjectByUser.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String subjectByUserToJson(SubjectByUser data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class SubjectByUser {
    SubjectByUser({
        this.success,
        this.subject,
    });

    int success;
    List<Subject> subject;

    factory SubjectByUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SubjectByUser(
        success: json["success"],
        subject: List<Subject>.from(json["subject"].map((x) => Subject.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "subject": List<dynamic>.from(subject.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Subject {
    Subject({
        this.subjectId,
        this.subjectName,
        this.image,
        this.active,
        this.standardId,
        this.mediumId,
    });

    String subjectId;
    String subjectName;
    String image;
    String active;
    String standardId;
    String mediumId;

    factory Subject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Subject(
        subjectId: json["subject_id"],
        subjectName: json["subject_name"],
        image: json["image"],
        active: json["active"],
        standardId: json["standard_id"],
        mediumId: json["medium_id"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "subject_id": subjectId,
        "subject_name": subjectName,
        "image": image,
        "active": active,
        "standard_id": standardId,
        "medium_id": mediumId,
    };
}
```

So how can i get all subjects details like subjectName and image in list view?
like Image on left side and name on right side for all subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list:

```
List<Subject> list = []; // <-- set the list

ListView.builder(itemCount: list.length, itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Column(children: [
        Text(list[index].subjectId), 
        Text(list[index].subjectName), 
        Text(list[index].image), 
        Text(list[index].active), 
        Text(list[index].standardId), 
        Text(list[index].mediumId), ],)
    },
```

Comment: i have to display the records based on users so can i dont have to use the SubjectByUser  class in function?

Comment: how can i display the records using SubjectByUser class?

Comment: Then you will have a SubjectByUser, and you get the list out of it. list = SubjectByUser.subject;